# ExpectedConditions OR AND AND in DefaultWait<T>

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In using C#, Selenium webdriver, I navigate to a page, which might redirect to a login screen or eventually redirect or not to the actual app page, depending on whether I have cached credentials or not. (case in point azure active dir auth).

What I am after is to find if a known element of my app page appears or the login screen of azure auth with an element id "use_another_account_link" appears.  SO I want to OR the condition of ExpectedConditions without having to wait N seconds on each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a CSS selector with two expessions separated by a `,` to implement the OR :

```c#
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("#id1, #id2")));
if (element.GetAttribute("id") == "id1") {
    // handle element with id="id1"
} else {
    // handle element with id="id2"
}
```

Or an XPath with two expessions separated by a `|`:

```c#
var element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("id('id1') | id('id2')")));
if (element.GetAttribute("id") == "id1") {
    // handle element with id="id1"
} else {
    // handle element with id="id2"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where you have to provide your own `Func<IWebElement, IWebElement>` to `IWait<IWebElement>.Until()`. You can write something specific like this:

```
(Func<IWebElement, IWebElement>)
  (return ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("use_another_account_link"))
  || ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("your_login_field_id")))
```

Or something generic like this:

```
public Func<IWebElement, IWebElement> Or(Func<IWebElement, IWebElement> either,
                                         Func<IWebElement, IWebElement> or) {
  return (Func<IWebElement, IWebElement>) either || or;
}
```

Comment: Note that I haven't compiled or tested either code snippet here.  But it's something like that.

Comment: Also note that a better option is often to check the top ID of the page (maybe there's one on the top div?) to do a best-guess as to which page you're on. You don't need to be rock solid in test code: 99.9% is good enough :)

Comment: ElementExists is not what it seems like. It does not seem to wait for the element to appear. The problem is that on a web page, it can incur several redirects and eventually land on the final page, and if the element does not exist on an intermediate page, the ElementExists seem to immediately return.

Comment: ElemenyExists isn't supposed to wait, that's what WebDriverWait.Until is for. Pass your Func to Until.

Comment: Indeed, I am using a waiter. That does seem to work if I use new WebDraiverWait().. but if I use the defaultwaiter, it does not seem to be working.

Comment: The source for WebDriverWait is easy to inspect, either in VS or in github. Check what it's doing, then compare it to DefaultWait

Answer (score 0):

**Wait until at least anyone condition returns true**

```
wait.until(
          ExpectedConditions.or(
               ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.name("Services")),
               ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.name("Products"))
               ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.name("Contact Us"))
          )
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is undoubtedly correct from a CSS/XPath perspective, however it may not always do what is expected when used with certain Selenium ExpectedConditions.
In the case where you want to wait for a login page to display, but also need to cater for the fact that this page will display either:

a userid entry field with the password field hidden, or;

a password entry field with the userid field hidden (userid read from cookies)

as is the case for eBay, then the following code will timeout in both cases.

```
WebElement login = (new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5))).until(
ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
By.cssSelector("input#userid, input#pass")
));
```

Instead it is necessary to use `ExpectedConditions.or` to determine whether either field is both present and visible:

```
boolean bDisplayed = (new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5))).until(ExpectedConditions.or(
ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#userid")), ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#pass"))
));
```

and then proceed to work out which field is visible.